# add row to a frame in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some code that creates a dataframe with 2 coulmns I want to write data from a forloop to this dataframe ...how do I do that?

```
df<-data.frame(id = numeric(), nobs = numeric())
  setwd(directory)
  files <-list.files(directory)
  files <-files[id]
  for (i in files) {
    #print(i)
    file <- read.csv(i)
    x <- nrow(file)
    num =  as.numeric(gsub(".csv","",i))
    y <- sprintf("%i %i", num, x)
    #print(y)

    df <- rbind(df,num,x)
  }
```

Comment: Is this an effort to get help on a Coursera assignment? And have you done any searching on SO? Pretty sure this has been asked and answered multiple itmes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add rows in a data.frame using a loop you can modify your code using the following one:

```
df<-data.frame(id = numeric(), nobs = numeric())
for (i in 1:1000) {
    df[i,] <- c(runif(1),runif(1))
}
```

However, if you know the number of rows needed then preallocating memory is strongly recommended:

```
files <- 1:1000
df<-data.frame(id = numeric(length(files)), nobs = numeric(length(files)))
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    df[i,] <- c(runif(1),runif(1))
}
```